# CSV header from parameter variables

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I have an `ArrayList<Metadata>` and I want to write it into a CSV file. I have a custom utility method that does the job:

```
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

CsvSchema csvSchema = csvMapper.schemaFor(clazz).withColumnSeparator(',');

csvSchema = csvSchema.withHeader();

csvMapper.writer(csvSchema).writeValue(output, list);
output.flush();
```

This is the `Metadata` class attributes:

```
private String name;
private String turnover;
```

I want to have a csv file that looks like this:

```
name, from jan to feb
john, 500$
Anna, 12$
Chris, 500$
```

The problem is that the column name `from jan to feb`, can change. I have two parameters `fromDate` and `toDate` which are passed as parameters in the method that builds the CSV file.

What is the simplest way to write this file header? (I want to change the utility method as little as possible)

Comment: You can have another class which will hold dates (to/from) and you can override it's to string method and then you can call it's .toString() to get your desired results.

Comment: How so? Where can I call it?

Comment: You can do that in constructor or fetch the results before creating MetaData object and then set it's attributes. Can you share full code of MetaData and the main class from where it's called?